# Using dummy condition to make sure multi-column index is used?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Let's say I have a database table with a multi-column index on columns (A, B, C). I want to do a

```
SELECT ... WHERE C BETWEEN c1 AND c2
```

which is slow because the index does not get used.

Does it make any sense to try and 'fool' SQL Server into using the index by including dummy conditions on A and B? I.e.:

```
SELECT ... WHERE ((A >= MIN_VALUE) OR A IS NULL) 
             AND ((B >= MIN_VALUE) OR B IS NULL) 
             AND (C BETWEEN c1 AND c2)
```

I cannot modify the table in any way.

Comment: Did you try your own solution to see if it works?

Comment: That index won't help the query at all. That's why SQL Server doesn't use it. `C` is the last column which means SQL Server will have to scan the *entire* index to find any matches, and *then* load the rest of the row

Comment: Trying it, but I am getting a lot of variability in my running times. Not sure if SQL Server is doing some caching of the results or whether the load on the server is highly variable - and I have no way of checking that. So I am curious if in principle it even makes sense, or if it is a very obviously bad idea.

Comment: @rinspy add an index where C is the first column if you want to speed up this query. You can use an INDEX hint to force SQL Server to use that index but you'll find out you won't gain anything

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A multi-column index on `(A, B, C)` is not going to be used for a condition that is only on `C`.

Your attempt to "fool" SQL Server indicates that you don't fully understand how indexes work.  Indexes are applied to conditions up-to and including the first inequality (actually, anything other than `=` or `is null`).

MySQL actually has a pretty [good explanation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/multiple-column-indexes.html) of how multi-column indexes are used.  What it says is generally true across databases (although some databases -- but not SQL Server -- have an additional operation called skip-scan which could be used in some additional cases).

Your index could be used for:

```
where A = @A and B = @B and C between @c1 and @c2
```

An index is not going to be used if `c1` and `c2` are columns in a table.  (Well, it might be used in a full index scan but not a lookup/seek.)

Comment: I see. So even if my condition was 'where A between a1 and a2 AND B between b1 and b2 AND C between c1 and c2', where all of those are legitimate ranges, the index will only help with the condition on A because that is the first inequality?

Comment: @rinspy . . . Basically yes.  The SQL engine will probably pull the values for `b` and `c` from the index; it is possible that the query would need no access to the data pages at all (if the index is a *covering index* for the query).